# How to agregate mongodb rows to columns

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pivot

is there a way to aggregate rows in to columns in Mongodb
here is the schema

```
[{
"_id" : "2020-04-17",
"wares" : [{"ware" : "NYC","total" : 5},{"ware" : "SFO","total" : 10}]
},
{
"_id" : "2020-04-18",
"wares" : [{"ware" : "NYC","total" : 6},{"ware" : "SFO","total" : 12},{"ware" : "CHI","total" : 13}]
}]
```

Final result should be like this

```
[
 {
   date: '2020-04-17', NYC: 5, SFO: 10
 },
 {
   date: '2020-04-18', NYC: 6, SFO: 12, CHI:13
 }
```

Comment: Will each `ware` value only ever appear once in a `wares` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        { "$arrayToObject": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$wares",
            "in": {
              "k": "$$this.ware",
              "v": "$$this.total"
            }
          }
        }},
        { "_id": "$_id" }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fn-mYt-53MY)

Comment: Excelent!! Thanks Ashh!!